# datagridviews in c# winforms

Tags: c#

I have created a datagridview with 3 columns as below :

- SR no
- tasks
- status(checkbox column)

I have to add 11 rows whose values I want to hardcode.
like sr no 1 to 11 and specific texts for tasks.
checkbox column should be initially all set to false.

what is the best way of doing it?
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a `DataGridView`, I usually prefer to define the content using databinding. A simple way is to create a class to represent your records, create a list of objects of this class, and assign it to the `DataSource` property of the DGV :

```
class SR
{
    public int SRNumber { get; set; }
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

...

var list = new List<SR>
{
    new SR { SRNumber = 1, Tasks = "Foo", Status = true },
    new SR { SRNumber = 2, Tasks = "Bar", Status = false },
    ...
};

dataGridView.DataSource = list;
```

In the designer, don't forget to map each column to a property of the `SR` class (set `DataPropertyName` to the name of the property)